# How can I go to top level UINavigationController in one UITabBarController from another UINavigationController in another UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

OK so this is the scenario:

I have a Tab bar application that has a UINavigationController in each tab. Lets say I have two tabs, "Home" and "Signout". In "Home" the user follows a UINavigation based navigation down 3 levels and presses submit. After that they click on "Signout", click on the signout button.

What I want to do is to:

Take the user back to the first tab "Home", and then do a "Pop to root navigation controller"

My code in Signout is :

```
[[self tabBarController]setSelectedIndex:0]; //this takes me to the first tab "Home"

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; //this does not work
```

How do I get about doing this?

Comment: AFAIK, your first line is frowned upon in Apple's guidelines. You shouldn't set tab item programmatically.

Comment: Why are you taking control to first tab and then popping navigation control at the same time. ?

Comment: I am taking user to home screen because they just clicked sign out. When the next time the user signs on, I want them to start from the same step every time and not the "signout" screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke the pop command on the proper controller, ie do something like:

```
UIViewController *selectedController = [[self tabBarController] selectedController];
[[selectedController navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```